# V4L-Utils & Vitis 2021.2 Build Instructions

Tags: c, compilation, libraries, libudev

I'm trying to build V4L-Utils using the [instructions](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18842180/V4L-Utils+Libdrm+Build+Instructions)

System:

- Vitis 2021.2,
- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Setup:

```
~$ source /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/settings64.sh
~$ source /home/max/petalinux/2021.2/settings.sh
~$ export INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
~$ ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --without-jpeg --with-udevdir=$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib/udev
 
...
compile time options summary
============================
 
    Host OS                    : linux-gnueabihf
    X11                        : yes
    GL                         : yes
    glu                        : yes
    libelf             : no
    libjpeg                    : 
    libudev                    : yes
    pthread                    : yes
    QT version                 : none
    ALSA support               : yes
    SDL support            : no
 
    build dynamic libs         : yes
    build static libs          : yes
 
    gconv                      : no
 
    dynamic libv4l             : yes
    v4l_plugins                : yes
    v4l_wrappers               : yes
    libdvbv5                   : yes
    dvbv5-daemon               : yes
    v4lutils                   : yes
    qv4l2                      : no
    qvidcap                    : no
    v4l2-ctl uses libv4l       : yes
    v4l2-ctl-32                : no
    v4l2-compliance            : yes
    v4l2-compliance uses libv4l: yes
    v4l2-compliance-32         : no
    BPF IR Decoders:           : no
 
~$ make 
...
  CC       libdvbv5_la-dvb-dev.lo
dvb-dev.c:19:10: fatal error: libudev.h: No such file or directory
   19 | #include <libudev.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I can confirm i have the `/usr/include/libudev.h` on my system...

The instruction is tied to the Xilinx Software Development Kit (SDK), so the question is how to build V4L-Utils with Vitis, if at all possible.

Comment: does the path to the "missing" file have to match the --with-udevdir configure option?

Comment: @user_1818839 Hi, 
the /usr/lib/udev folder exists.  
Or what do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
~$ export INSTALL_PREFIX=/tools/Xilinx/Vitis/2021.2/gnu/aarch32/lin/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/cortexa9t2hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/usr
~$ ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --without-jpeg --with-udevdir=$INSTALL_PREFIX/lib/udev
~$ make -j16
~$ make install DESTDIR=$INSTALL_PREFIX
```